# I cannot use --package option on bitnami/spark docker container

Tags: docker, apache-spark, elasticsearch

I pulled docker image and executed below command to run image.

1. docker run -it bitnami/spark:latest /bin/bash
2. spark-shell --packages="org.elasticsearch:elasticsearch-spark-20_2.11:7.5.0"

and i got message like below

```
Ivy Default Cache set to: /opt/bitnami/spark/.ivy2/cache
The jars for the packages stored in: /opt/bitnami/spark/.ivy2/jars
:: loading settings :: url = jar:file:/opt/bitnami/spark/jars/ivy-2.4.0.jar!/org/apache/ivy/core/settings/ivysettings.xml
org.elasticsearch#elasticsearch-spark-20_2.11 added as a dependency
:: resolving dependencies :: org.apache.spark#spark-submit-parent-c785f3e6-7c78-469f-ab46-451f8be61a4c;1.0
        confs: [default]
Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: /opt/bitnami/spark/.ivy2/cache/resolved-org.apache.spark-spark-submit-parent-c785f3e6-7c78-469f-ab46-451f8be61a4c-1.0.xml (No such file or directory)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.open0(Native Method)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(FileOutputStream.java:270)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:213)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:162)
        at org.apache.ivy.plugins.parser.xml.XmlModuleDescriptorWriter.write(XmlModuleDescriptorWriter.java:70)
        at org.apache.ivy.plugins.parser.xml.XmlModuleDescriptorWriter.write(XmlModuleDescriptorWriter.java:62)
        at org.apache.ivy.core.module.descriptor.DefaultModuleDescriptor.toIvyFile(DefaultModuleDescriptor.java:563)
        at org.apache.ivy.core.cache.DefaultResolutionCacheManager.saveResolvedModuleDescriptor(DefaultResolutionCacheManager.java:176)
        at org.apache.ivy.core.resolve.ResolveEngine.resolve(ResolveEngine.java:245)
        at org.apache.ivy.Ivy.resolve(Ivy.java:523)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmitUtils$.resolveMavenCoordinates(SparkSubmit.scala:1300)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.DependencyUtils$.resolveMavenDependencies(DependencyUtils.scala:54)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.prepareSubmitEnvironment(SparkSubmit.scala:304)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:774)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:161)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:184)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:86)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$$anon$2.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:920)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:929)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
```

I tried other package, but it is not working with all same error message.

Can you give some advice to avoid this error?

Comment: Can you verify that bitnami/spark image ships with the package that you need?

Comment: facing the same issue.

Answer (score 4):

Found the solution to it
as given in https://github.com/bitnami/bitnami-docker-spark/issues/7
what we have to do is create a volume on host mapped to docker path

> ```
> volumes:
>   - ./jars_dir:/opt/bitnami/spark/ivy:z
> ```

give this path as cache path like this

> spark-shell --conf spark.jars.ivy=/opt/bitnami/spark/ivy --conf
> spark.cassandra.connection.host=127.0.0.1 --packages
> com.datastax.spark:spark-cassandra-connector_2.12:3.0.0-beta  --conf
> spark.sql.extensions=com.datastax.spark.connector.CassandraSparkExtensions

All happened because /opt/bitnami/spark is not writable and we have to mount a volume to bypass that.

Answer (score 1):

The error "java.io.FileNotFoundException: /opt/bitnami/spark/.ivy2/" occured because the location /opt/bitnami/spark/ is not writable. so in order to resolve this issue do modify the master spark service like this.
Added user as root and add mounted volume path for required jars.

**see the working block of spark service written in docker compose**:

```
spark:
image: docker.io/bitnami/spark:3
container_name: spark
environment:
  - SPARK_MODE=master
  - SPARK_RPC_AUTHENTICATION_ENABLED=no
  - SPARK_RPC_ENCRYPTION_ENABLED=no
  - SPARK_LOCAL_STORAGE_ENCRYPTION_ENABLED=no
  - SPARK_SSL_ENABLED=no
user: root
ports:
  - '8880:8080'
volumes:
  - ./spark-defaults.conf:/opt/bitnami/spark/conf/spark-defaults.conf
  - ./jars_dir:/opt/bitnami/spark/ivy:z
```

Comment: Thanks. I am having the same issue but i am using it on kubernetes with helm charts. What setting we need to change do when we use helm charts by bitnami from https://github.com/bitnami/charts/tree/master/bitnami/spark ?